# Find the exact value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2[f(x)]^{10} \,dx$

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

Let $f(x)$ be the pdf of a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variable $\sigma^2$.
Find the exact value of $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2[f(x)]^{10} \,dx$$

I understand that $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2]$. I noticed that if $f(x)$ is a standard normal then that integral goes to $1$ but I am not sure how to find the exact value for a normal distribution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After expanding the power of $10$, it becomes
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2 \frac{1}{\sigma^{10}(2\pi)^5} e^{-\frac{5}{\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2}dx$$

This is equal to $$\frac{1}{\sigma^9\sqrt{10}(2\pi)^5\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2 \frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_1^2}(x-\mu)^2}dx$$

where $\sigma_1=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{10}}$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes thank you! I see how to do it now. From here, the integral part is clearly E(X^2) so we find this by getting the mgf M''(0).

Comment: Yep, and for finding $E[X^2]$, you can use that $E[X^2] = \text{Var}(X) + E[X]^2$